Open and dense subsets of continous functions with respect to L1-norm
I am having an issue with an exercise that is concerned with the $L^1$-norm on the space of continous real-valued functions. More, specifically I am in doubt whether my solutions are correct.

I am concerned about my solutions for b).
In order to show that $A_n$ is open I considered $f \in A_n$. Then $||f||_{\infty}>n$. Choose $\varepsilon>0$ such that $n+\varepsilon < ||f||_1$ and consider the open ball $B_{\varepsilon} (f)$ around $f$ with respect to the $L^1$-norm. Then
$$
||g||_{\infty} - n                              
>||g||_1 - n                                        
>||g||_1 - (||f-g||_1 - \varepsilon + ||g||_1)   
=\varepsilon - ||f-g||_1                        
>0.
$$
This implies that $g \in A_n$ and hence $A_n$ is open. However, I'm in doubt whether my choice for $\varepsilon$ is actually valid. If we considered open balls with respect to $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$ the argument would work since $||f||_{\infty}>n$. Are there cases where $||f||_{ \infty} > n $ but $||f||_{1}=n$? If so, what would be the correct choice for $\varepsilon$?
In order to show that $A_n$ is dense in $X$ I have to show that the closure of $A_n$ satisfies $\bar{A}_n=X$. So for $f \in X$ I need to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$ the open ball $B_{\varepsilon}(f)$ around $f$ of radius $\varepsilon$ satisfies $B_{\varepsilon}(f) \cap A_n \neq \emptyset$.
So I need to find $g \in X$ such that
$$
||f-g||_1=\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)-g(x)| dx <\varepsilon \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
||g||_{\infty} > n. \tag{2}
$$
Assume w.l.o.g.that $f \notin A_n$. Then $f(x) \leq n$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Because $f$ is continous we know that there is $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f$ takes its minimum in $x_0$. Choose $0<\delta<1$ and consider the function
$$
g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, \
g(x)=\begin{cases}
    k_1 (x-(x_0-\delta \varepsilon)) + l_1 &, x \in [x_0-\delta \varepsilon, x_0]  \\
    k_2 (x-x_0)+l_2                        &, x \in [x_0, x_0+\delta \varepsilon] \\  
    f(x)                                   &, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where
$$
k_1=\frac{n + \varepsilon - f(x_0-\delta \varepsilon)}{\delta \varepsilon}, \
l_1=f(x_0-\delta \varepsilon)                                               \\
k_2=\frac{f(x_0+\delta \varepsilon)-(n+\varepsilon)}{\delta \varepsilon},   \
l_2=n+\varepsilon. 
$$
Then $g$ should take the value $n+\varepsilon$ at $x_0$ so that $(2)$ is satisfied. Moreover, since $\delta$ can be choosen arbitrarily close to $0$ $g$ should deviate from $f$ only on an arbitrarily small neighborhood
$[x_0-\delta \varepsilon, x_0+\delta \varepsilon]$. Then
$$
||f-g||_{1}
=\int_{x_0-\delta \varepsilon}^{x_0+\delta \varepsilon} |f(x)-g(x)|
\leq 2 \delta \varepsilon. 
$$
Since $\delta$ can be choosen arbitrarily close to $0$ I should get
$2 \delta \varepsilon<\varepsilon$ so that $(1)$ is satisfied. This proves that $A_n$ is dense in $X$.
Is my construction valid or am I missing something? If so, how could it be fixed?

The first part is incorrect. The condition $|f|_\infty >n$ does not imply that $|f|_1\ge n+\varepsilon. $ The norm $|f|_1$ can be arbitrarily small.

The solution of the density can be made simpler.
The functions $f_k(x)=kx^{k^2-1}$ satisfy $\|f_k\|_1=1/k$ and $\|f_k\|_\infty=k.$ For any function $f\in X$ we have $\|(f+f_k)- f\|_1\to 0$  and $$\|f +f_k\|_\infty \ge \|f_k\|_\infty -\|f\|_\infty =k-\|f\|_\infty$$ Thus $f+f_k\in A_n$ for $k>n+\|f\|_\infty.$
Concerning openess let $f\in A_n.$ Then there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$C:=\{x\,:\, |f(x)|> n+\delta\}\neq \emptyset$$
Assume $g\notin A_n.$ Then $|g(x)|\le n$ for any $x.$ Hence
$$\|f-g\|_1\ge \int\limits_C|f(x)-g(x)|\,dx\ge \int\limits_C[|f(x)|-|g(x)|]\,dx
\ge \delta|C|$$
Therefore the open ball with radius $\delta|C|$ centered at $f$ is contained in $A_n.$
